# Getting a mistake with shap plotting

Tags: python, shap

```
X = df.copy()

# Save and drop labels
y = df['class']
X = X.drop('class', axis=1)
cat_features = list(range(0, X.shape[1]))
model = CatBoostClassifier(iterations=2000, learning_rate=0.1, random_seed=12)
model.fit(X, y,  verbose=False, plot=False)

explainer = shap.Explainer(model)
shap_values = explainer(X)

shap.force_plot(explainer.expected_value, shap_values[0:5,:],X.iloc[0:5,:], plot_cmap="DrDb")

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-170-ba1eca12b9ed> in <module>
----> 1 shap.force_plot(10, shap_values[0:5,:],X.iloc[0:5,:], plot_cmap="DrDb")

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\shap\plots\_force.py in force(base_value, shap_values, features, feature_names, out_names, link, plot_cmap, matplotlib, show, figsize, ordering_keys, ordering_keys_time_format, text_rotation, contribution_threshold)
    101 
    102     if type(shap_values) != np.ndarray:
--> 103         return visualize(shap_values)
    104 
    105     # convert from a DataFrame or other types

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\shap\plots\_force.py in visualize(e, plot_cmap, matplotlib, figsize, show, ordering_keys, ordering_keys_time_format, text_rotation, min_perc)
    343             return AdditiveForceArrayVisualizer(e, plot_cmap=plot_cmap, ordering_keys=ordering_keys, ordering_keys_time_format=ordering_keys_time_format)
    344     else:
--> 345         assert False, "visualize() can only display Explanation objects (or arrays of them)!"
    346 
    347 class BaseVisualizer:

AssertionError: visualize() can only display Explanation objects (or arrays of them)!
```

Was trying to plot with shap and my data, but got a mistake and I actually don't understand why. Haven't found anything about this. Please explain how to avoid this error?

```
explainer.expected_value
-5.842052267820879
```

Comment: A [reprex] may help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should change the last line to this : `shap.force_plot(explainer.expected_value, shap_values.values[0:5,:],X.iloc[0:5,:], plot_cmap="DrDb")`

by calling `shap_values.values` instead of just `shap_values`, because `shap_values` holds the shapley values, the `base_values` and the `data` . I had the same problem until I inspected the variable.

Comment: thank you, this worked for me. shap's documentation examples are in dire need of updating

Comment: I get AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'values'.